# $r^2=\sin{2\theta}$: how to find vertical and horizontal tangents?

Tags: calculus

So I have computed $$\frac{dx}{d\theta} = \frac{\cos{3\theta}}{r}$$ and $$\frac{dy}{d\theta} = \frac{\sin{3\theta}}{r}$$

I set these equal to zero and found the horizontal tangents to occur in the following points:

$$(0,0), (\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}},\frac{\pi}{3})\text{ and }(\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}},\frac{4\pi}{3})$$

However if $r=0$, then $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ is undefined, however the limit as $\theta$ approaches $0$ of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ appears to be $0$, so that would indicate a horizontal tangent.

So is $(0,0)$ a point of a horizontal tangent? Likewise the same is true for $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ (that is, $r=0$ makes $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ undefined). So does that mean then that we have $(0,0)$ has both a horizontal and vertical tangent? It also appears from the graph, that this is possible, but I am just not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @RandomUser the x coordinates should be (3/4)^(1/4)

Comment: I realized that it looked messed up after my edit. It's been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}\cdot \frac{d\theta}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$$ and we want to know when $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$.

$$\frac{dx}{d\theta} = \frac{\cos3\theta}{r},\quad \frac{dy}{d\theta} = \frac{\sin 3\theta}{r} \implies \dfrac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{\sin{3\theta}}{r}\cdot \dfrac{r}{\cos 3\theta}$$

Now solve for when $$\require{cancel} \dfrac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{\sin{3\theta}}{\cancel{r}}\cdot \dfrac{\cancel{r}}{\cos 3\theta} = = \tan(3\theta)= 0$$

That's going to happen when $\sin 3\theta = 0$ (and note that when $\sin{3\theta} = 0 \iff 3\theta = k \pi \iff \theta = k\pi/3\;$ ($k$ any integer), we have that $\cos 3\theta = \pm 1\iff 3\theta = k\pi \iff \theta = k\pi/3$.)

The points at which the tangents are horizontal and/or vertical are given in *polar* coordinates, $(r, \theta)$.

[image]

Comment: but what about theta = 0?

Comment: Theta can equal zero, since $\theta = 0 = \dfrac {0\cdot \pi}{3}$.  Question: Are you sure you posted the correct equation in the title? I answered based on what you found to be $\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}$ and $\dfrac{dx}{d\theta}$.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct equation. My question is basically whether or not the polar coordinate (0,0) serves as both a horizontal and vertical tangent?

Comment: Yes, both the vertical line and horizontal line is tangent to the curve at $(0,0).$ I'll post a graph of the function so you can see its behavior at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid solving for $x$ or $y$. Using the polar angle $t$ as parameter we have
$$x(t)=\sqrt{\sin(2t)}\>\cos t,\quad y(t)=\sqrt{\sin(2t)}\>\sin t\tag{1}$$ for all $t\in{\mathbb R}/(2\pi{\mathbb Z})$ with $\sin(2t)\geq0$. The latter is the case for $0\leq t\leq{\pi\over2}$ and for $\pi\leq t\leq{3\pi\over2}$. One computes
$$x'(t)={\cos(3t)\over\sqrt{\sin(2t)}},\quad  y'(t)={\sin(3t)\over\sqrt{\sin(2t)}}\ ,$$
so that one obtains the unit tangent vector
$$\dot{\bf z}(t)=\bigl(\cos(3t),\sin(3t)\bigr)$$
along this curve. Note that when $\sin(2t)=0$ the vector $\bigl(x'(t),y'(t)\bigr)$ becomes undefined, but $\dot{\bf z}$ exists "in the limit", and is also the limiting secant direction at the corresponding curve point $(0,0)$.

It follows that the tangent is vertical at the admisible $t$ for which $\cos(3t)=0$, and is horizontal at the admissible $t$ for which $\sin(3t)=0$. The first is the case for $t\in\bigl\{{\pi\over6},{\pi\over2},{5\pi\over6},{3\pi\over2}\bigr\}$, the second for
$t\in\bigl\{0,{\pi\over3},\pi,{4\pi\over3}\bigr\}$. The corresponding points $(x,y)$ on the curve can now be computed from $(1)$; the point $(0,0)$ appears four times in this list.